# How do I reshape this time series multiindexed dataframe into its "transpose"?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Not really looking for a transpose (I don't think), but I could not think of a better descriptor.

I have this dataframe:

```
ticker     2282 JP Equity                 3401 JP Equity          
field               OP007   OP008          OP007   OP008   
2017-02-01         0.5193  1.0732          0.647  1.8618
```

It is a time series of 1 value, so not really a time series. I want this:

```
                  OP007   OP008
2282 JP Equity   0.5193  1.0732
3401 JP Equity    0.647  1.8618
```

Making the level 1 column header the row index, and the level 2 column header the new column index. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: do you not want the date?

Comment: I do not want the date, but I just used your suggestion and then re-indexed (drop_level) to remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `stack`

```
df.stack('ticker')
```

Or

```
df.stack(0)
```

***demo***

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[0.5193, 1.0732, 0.647, 1.8618]],
    pd.to_datetime(['2017-02-01']),
    pd.MultiIndex.from_product([
            ['2282 JP Equity', '3401 JP Equity'],
            ['OP007', 'OP008']
        ], names=['ticker', 'field'])
)

df

ticker     2282 JP Equity         3401 JP Equity        
field               OP007   OP008          OP007   OP008
2017-02-01         0.5193  1.0732          0.647  1.8618
```

Then

```
df.stack('ticker')

field                       OP007   OP008
           ticker                        
2017-02-01 2282 JP Equity  0.5193  1.0732
           3401 JP Equity  0.6470  1.8618
```

Comment: Aha! I just learned about 'unstack' yesterday. Did not even think to try 'stack'. Thanks!!

Comment: @lukehawk glad I could help